# Запись в бд с помощью sequalize

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, sequelize.js

Не могу понять почему когда с разных аккаунтов угадываешь числа, количество верных и неверных ответов на каком то чисто рандомном уровне записываются в бд. Вроде как все с await, добавил инкремент.

````
const { gameOptions, againOptions } = require("./options");
const sequelize = require("./db");
const UserModel = require("./models");

const token = "6887914721:AAFz-rTCnY1Ph1KO3yKveLyuX52XucyU0Fc";

const bot = new TelegramApi(token, { polling: true });

const chats = {};

const startGame = async (chatId) => {
  await bot.sendMessage(chatId, "Угадай цифру от 0 до 9");
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  chats[chatId] = randomNumber;
  await bot.sendSticker(
    chatId,
    "https://a127fb2c-de1c-4ae0-af0d-3808559ec217.selcdn.net/stickers/711/2ce/7112ce51-3cc1-42ca-8de7-62e7525dc332/256/2.webp"
  );
  await bot.sendMessage(chatId, "Угадывай...", gameOptions);
};

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    await sequelize.sync();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Подключение к бд сломалось", e);
  }
  bot.setMyCommands([
    { command: "/start", description: "Начальное приветсвтие" },
    { command: "/info", description: "Информация о пользователе" },
    { command: "/game", description: "Начать игру" },
  ]);

  bot.on("message", async (msg) => {
    const text = msg.text;
    const chatId = msg.chat.id;

    try {
      if (text === "/start") {
        await UserModel.create({ chatId });
        await bot.sendSticker(
          chatId,
          "https://a127fb2c-de1c-4ae0-af0d-3808559ec217.selcdn.net/stickers/be1/98c/be198cd5-121f-4f41-9cc0-e246df7c210d/256/1.webp"
        );
        return bot.sendMessage(
          chatId,
          Добро пожаловать в телеграм бот AlexKey
        );
      }
      if (text === "/info") {
        const user = await UserModel.findOne({ chatId });
        return bot.sendMessage(
          chatId,
          Тебя зовут ${msg.from.first_name} ${msg.from.last_name}. В игре у тебя ${user.right} правильных ответов, ${user.wrong} неправильных ответов.
        );
      }

      if (text === "/game") {
        return startGame(chatId);
      }
      return bot.sendMessage(chatId, "Меня твоя не понимать.");
    } catch (e) {
      return bot.sendMessage(chatId, "Произошла ошибОЧКА");
    }
  });

  bot.on("callback_query", async (msg) => {
    const data = msg.data;
    const chatId = msg.message.chat.id;
    if (data === "/again") {
      return startGame(chatId);
    }
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ chatId });
    await bot.sendMessage(chatId, ${chatId});
    if (data == chats[chatId]) {
      await user.increment("right");
      await bot.sendMessage(
        chatId,
        Поздравляю, ты угадал цифру ${chats[chatId]},
        againOptions
      );
    } else {
      await user.increment("wrong");
      await bot.sendMessage(
        chatId,
        Сорян, ты промазал, я загадал цифру ${chats[chatId]},
        againOptions
      );
    }
    await user.save();
  });
};
start();```
````